# Rigid body options not working properly

Tags: rigidbody

[image]I'm trying to make a conveyor belt with a cube on it. I used curve and then a cube to which I added an *Array Modifier* and then curve modifier. When I added the cube over it and applied Rigid Body physics, it started flying in whatever direction it likes.

I have applied rigid body to the cube/ sphere on the conveyor belt but the cube sometimes go straight and when i play again... it goes into the air.. rotating and flying ...

[Blend File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RJrebJrjzmRBc6CyeRlQMQdkiPFFWZ9O/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: No link. Use blend-exchange.com Also, please add screenshots.

Comment: there is. it was hidden in the post xd. i added it for him :)